# How to create a drop down menu effect over an existing layer? Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cclayer

I have my main layer with an options button and when I press the button I am calling pushScene on a CCLayerColor Layer, and the layer is only half the size of the screen because I want it to be like a drop down menu but when it appears with the transition that I have set up, the background layer goes black. I would like the background layer to always stay visible. I am pretty sure that the background layer is getting deallocated.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `pushScene:`, previous scene will not be deallocated. It will be restored after sending `popScene` message. As far as I understood, your disappeared "background layer" is previous scene. Scene that is not on the top of the scene stack will not receive `visit` messages, so it simply will not be drawn. Thats why it is disappeared.

Anyway, why do you use another scene for dropdown menu? Create separate layer and simply show/hide or add/remove it when you need.

Comment: thanks for the help. Is there no way to make the background layer visible with the other layer that I am pushing on to the stack?

Comment: you say about no layer, but whole scene. normally only one scene draws it's content.

Comment: Could you explain a little further, I don't know if I understand what you are telling?